# * or dagger footnotes value change in tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht

I am new to tex and converting html using tex4ht option, while converting my tex file * footnotes changed to 1 in converted html files.

Latex File

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\makeatletter
\def\exercisehead#1{\par%
\centerline{\normalfont\bfseries#1}\par
}
\makeatother
%\usepackage[active, generate=file, extract-env={figure}]{extract}

\newcommand{\omegav}{\boldsymbol{\omega}}
\newcommand{\gradv}{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}
\newcommand{\gammav}{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}
\newcommand{\zetav}{\boldsymbol{\zeta}}
\newcommand{\lv}{\boldsymbol{\ell}}
\newcommand{\sigmav}{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}
\newcommand{\varepsilonv}{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}     %Bibliography: Author-Date system
\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\hspace*{2cm}---Albert Einstein, letter to David Hilbert, May 24,
1918\index{Einstein, Albert}\footnote{[Calaprice (1996), Byers
(1999)]} in Yvette Kosmann-Schwarzbach, \textit{The Noether
Theorems: Invariance and Conservation Laws in the Twentieth
Century}, translated by Betram E. Schwarzbach, 2010, 71--72

\bigskip

\end{document}
```

HTML Output

```
<p class="noindent" >&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;                 &#x2014;Albert Einstein, letter to David Hilbert, May 24,
1918<a 
 id="dx1-2"></a><span class="footnote-mark"><a 
href="#fn1x0" id="fn1x0-bk"><sup class="textsuperscript">1</sup></a></span><a 
 id="x1-3f1"></a>
in Yvette Kosmann-Schwarzbach, The Noether Theorems: Invariance and
Conservation Laws in the Twentieth Century, translated by Betram E.
Schwarzbach, 2010, 71&#x2013;72
</p>
```

TeX4ht Commands

```
htlatex filename "xhtml" " -cunihft" "-cvalidate -p"
```

PDF Output

[image]

Looking for any suggestions

Thanks,
Mustafa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please place the tag `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` before  `\begin{document}`, then run the conversion mode...